# How can I copy visual studio 2013 trial?

Tags: visual-studio

I have downloaded visual studio 2013 trial for 3 month through microsoft. The installer itself had about 1mb, and then the whole program was downloaded and installed.

Now I am looking for a way to create an iso file from it and copy it to the friend's computer. How can I do that? I can't create an iso from c:/programFiles, because of the registry, and I don't see the exe file anywhere.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Trying to build an ISO it is very complicated. It is not a good idea to re-invent the wheel. **Microsoft is already creating these ISOS so the best option is download ISO directly**... it is much easier. You should look into Microsoft site for direct ISO download. Here is the current link: https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/profile/review?download=true&family=VisualStudio&edition=Ultimate&release=VisualStudio2013Upd4&type=iso&slcid=0x409

There are also more options that **might** suit you better:

- If you are a student you can have **Visual Studio 2013 Professional** for free: https://www.dreamspark.com/Default.aspx
- You can also download **Visual Studio 2013 Community** instead of trial, if you meet the [requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) (TL/DR: You can get it if you are an individual Dev, if you are in a classroom, if you are contributing to OpenSource projects or in non-enterprise organizations with 5 devs or less) : http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9863609
- Or even better **Visual Studio 2015 Community**: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/visual-studio-2015-ctp-vs

Answer (score 0):

You need go to this link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx and download ISO image directly instead of online install package.